# Polymorphism with Objectify 5

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have this classes:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
public abstract class PostRecord {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String field1;
}

@Subclass(name = "Bulletin")
public class BulletinRecord extends PostRecord {

    private String field2;
}

@Subclass(name = "Session")
public class SessionRecord extends PostRecord {

    private String field3;
}
```

**How i do to fetch all bulletins or all sessions?**

This code below work fine and return a post list with all bulletins and sessions:

```
ofy().load().type(PostRecord.class).list();
```

but i want just bulletins or just sessions, and when i try this code below, i get an empty list:

```
ofy().load().type(BulletinRecord.class).list();
ofy().load().type(SessionRecord.class).list();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to index the subclass discriminators.

```
@Subclass(name = "Bulletin", index = true)
public class BulletinRecord extends PostRecord {
}
```

All filtering (such as subclass filtering) in GAE requires an index; indexes have a cost; Objectify requires you to opt-in to this cost.